# FX Cop still erroring after i suppress

Tags: model-view-controller, fxcop

```
<System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1045:DoNotPassTypesByReference", Justification:="Needs function to return two values.")> _
<System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic", Justification:="Needs function to return two values.")> _
```

I am trying to suppress these two errors.  I put them right above the method. But after i build i am still getting errors

Does anyone know of a reason why this would not suppress the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add the CODE_ANALYSIS compilation flag to your project.